# how to spot and fix differences between eclipse and maven build?

Tags: eclipse, maven

My project builds and tests under Eclipse, and the exported product runs fine.

The same project fails the UI tests, and the exported product also fails on running when compiled using maven.

My goal is to be able to use maven.

Source: https://github.com/magwas/zenta/tree/62066a22663d90fd6f036c9b6b5f34911f875bd1

The difference between file lists for the two generated products (DATE denotes a date-like string, which is different for the two products; when there is no .jar ending, then there is a directory with additional contents instead of a jar file. The packaged jre for the eclipse version is openjdk 8):

```
--- Zenta.eclipse.list  2016-01-23 22:39:30.783376017 +0100
+++ Zenta.mvn.list  2016-01-23 22:39:30.803376017 +0100
@@ -1,511 +1,27 @@
+./Zenta/artifacts.xml
-./Zenta/.eclipseproduct
 ./Zenta/icon.xpm
-./Zenta/jre
+./Zenta/p2
-./Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.draw2d_3.9.101.201408150207.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.draw2d_3.10.1.201508170204.jar
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.canvas_2.4.0.DATE
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor_2.4.0.DATE
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.export_2.2.0.DATE
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.canvas_2.4.0.DATE.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor_2.4.0.DATE.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.export_2.2.0.DATE.jar
 ./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.help_2.4.0.DATE
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.model_2.4.0.DATE
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.templates_2.4.0.DATE
-./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.widgets_2.4.0.DATE
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.model_2.4.0.DATE.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.templates_2.4.0.DATE.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.widgets_2.4.0.DATE.jar
-./Zenta/plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011.jar
+./Zenta/plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar
-./Zenta/plugins/uk.ac.bolton.jdom_1.1.1.DATE
+./Zenta/plugins/uk.ac.bolton.jdom_1.1.1.DATE.jar
+./Zenta/Zenta.ini
```

The log file of running the maven-built product:

```
!SESSION 2016-01-23 23:00:47.725 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_72-internal
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-23 23:00:48.935
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

org.eclipse.core.runtime seems to be the same for both:

```
$ find |grep org.eclipse.core.runtime
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318-2214.jar
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/.api_description
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/fragment.properties
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/about.html
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/runtime_registry_compatibility.jar
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.2.200.v20140128-0851.jar
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTable.7
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTable.8
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTableLock
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.mainData.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.contributors.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.contributions.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.table.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.orphans.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.namespaces.1
./Zenta.eclipse/Zenta/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.extraData.1
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.10.0.v20140318-2214.jar
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/.api_description
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/fragment.properties
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/about.html
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.300.v20140128-0851/runtime_registry_compatibility.jar
./Zenta.mvn/Zenta/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility_3.2.200.v20140128-0851.jar
```

Comment: It seems your project use Eclipse libraries. Eclipse IDE provides them by default but Maven knows nothing about them. Can you provide your pom?

Comment: There are multiple poms. Added a link to the current state of source.
The top level pom contains the repository links. Tried to add all relevant ones from eclipse. It does seem that maven finds them all, although slightly different versions.

Comment: It seems that the link is about the feature/fixit branch. Can you confirm.

Comment: Using the feature/fixit branch, the command "mvn clean package" runs fine (only two non blocking errors with project "org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor.build"). I'm using Oracle JVM 1.8.0_40 and Maven 3.3.3

Comment: I am using "mvn clean install", as I want to run the integration tests as well.
That fails horribly. Also the generated package (at least for linux_x86_64) does not run properly. See the error log above.
Yes, we are talking about the current state of the feature/fixbuild branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least four issues:

- To avoid messages "Could not acquire PlatformAdmin server" during UTs and ITs, add to the parent pom, in target-platform-configuration's configuration section:

```
<dependency-resolution>
  <extraRequirements>
    <requirement>
      <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
      <id>org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state</id>
      <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
    </requirement>
  </extraRequirements>
</dependency-resolution>
```

and to org.rulez.magwas.zenta.integrationtests pom, in tycho-surefire-plugin's configuration section:

```
<dependency>
  <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- To avoid messages "Event Admin service is not available, unable to publish event org.osgi.service.event.Event", 
  add to org.rulez.magwas.zenta.integrationtests pom, in tycho-surefire-plugin's configuration section:

  ```
      <dependency>
        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.event</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
  ```
- Upgrade to Eclipse Mars to avoid the bug:
       [Bug 449485 - [QuickAccess] "Widget is disposed" exception in errorlog during shutdown due to quickaccess.SearchField.storeDialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449485).
  Change the repositories in parent pom:

```
<repository>
  <id>4.5</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>orbit</id>
  <layout>p2</layout>
  <url>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150821153341/repository/</url>
</repository>
```

- Aftermath: since Eclipse Mars, 32 bit cocoa support was removed.
  cf. http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/msg07799.html
  Remove support for Mac OS X 32 bits in :

  - org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor.launch.macos
  - org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor.fullscreen.macos
- Remove mockito-core-debian.jar from org.rulez.magwas.zenta.integrationtests' .classpath

There are still 6 errors during integration tests. They seem related to the tests themselves.

Comment: Upps. When starting, I still have this:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-02-02 12:23:01.467
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).


I leave the upvote and the accept because you have clearly invested a lot in answering.

Comment: The start problem was resolved by adding the recommended entries to product configuration. Now the eclipse-built product have launch problems :(

Comment: I hadn't even tried to start the application as I had still integration test errors (see my answer). I just did a "mvn clean verify".

Comment: It seems that you are now working on a "feature/fix_maven_build", not "feature/fixbuild" anymore.